# How to access JSON data passed to c in jni?

Tags: c, json, java-native-interface

My java program passes JSONObject to native program like this:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

class json{

static{
    System.loadLibrary("json");
}

private native void json(JSONObject j);

public static void main(String args[]){
    json js = new json();
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("name","someone");
    j.put("age", 15);
    js.json(j);

}
}
```

how to access these data in c?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include "json.h"
#include "cJSON.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_json_json(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject j){


return;
}
```

i couldn't find any reference on how to access json data from jobject in c.
I'm new to jni. is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing the JSON data from the C code via JNI is not much different from accessing it via Java. In Java you would write:

```
System.out.println("name = " + j.get("name"));
System.out.println("age = " + j.get("age"));
```

The C code is basically the same, just much more verbose, since

1. You need to get the class object to call methods on them
2. You need to construct `jstring` instances for the keys passed to `get`
3. You must convert the `jstring` you get from `j.get("name")` to a C string
4. You must release that string after use
5. You must manually unbox the `java.lang.Integer` that you get

The code below does just that:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<jni.h>
#include "json.h"
// Notice that "cJSON.h" is not needed

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_json_json(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject json) {

    // Get the Class object for JSONObject.
    jclass JSONObjectClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, json);

    // Get the ID of the "get" method that we must call.
    // Notice that due to type erasure, both the parameter and the return value
    // are just plain Objects in the type signature.
    jmethodID getID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, JSONObjectClass, "get", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    if (getID == NULL) return;

    // Create java.lang.String instances for the keys we pass to j.get.
    jstring nameKey = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "name");
    jstring ageKey = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "age");
    if (nameKey == NULL || ageKey == NULL) return;

    // Actually get the name object. Since we know that the value added
    // in the Java code is a string, we just cast the jobject to jstring.
    jstring name = (jstring) (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, json, getID, nameKey);
    if (name == NULL) return;

    // Get a C string that can be used with the usual C functions.
    const char *name_cstr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, name, NULL);
    if (name_cstr == NULL) return;

    printf("name = %s\n", name_cstr);

    // Once done, the string must be released.
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, name, name_cstr);
    name_cstr = NULL;

    // Get the java.lang.Integer object representing the age.
    jobject ageObj = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, json, getID, ageKey);
    if (ageObj == NULL) return;

    // Unbox the java.lang.Integer manually.
    jclass IntegerClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, ageObj);
    jmethodID intValueID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, IntegerClass, "intValue", "()I");
    if (intValueID == NULL) return;

    jint age = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, ageObj, intValueID);

    printf("age = %d\n", (int) age);
}
```

More complicated use is done the same way: Check what you would write in Java, and find a way to call the same methods with the same values in C using the [JNI functions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/specs/jni/).